# Allow markup in edit comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, edits

Maybe that's overkill. But I just thought that adding markup in edit comments might be useful as well...

An example: my revision 2 in

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8149545/2

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to tell us that you've added a tag when it's clearly shown anyway?

Comment: You could simply use "added a relevant tag."

Comment: It's an example. You could have any sort of markup...

Comment: do we need bold/italic/whatnot in edit comments? also [Random](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) seems to get on fine without them in his...interesting...edit comments. [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/112037/3) for an example.

Comment: @tombull89: Very nice. I'm sure [Random](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) would be a big fan of this idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe that's overkill.

Yes, it is.

Comment: I guess it really is