# Add anchors to revisions

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

I just wanted to refer to revision 2 in a question. The question on meta is [Allow markup in edit comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112378/allow-markup-in-edit-comments), and these are the revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8149545/revisions.

It would be nice to be able to refer to a particular revision, such as with the following URLs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8149545/revisions#2
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8149545/revisions#56c3139b-04f7-47c1-8a3a-fab0270ccaa7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking on the `link` link on any revision's colour bar in a [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8149545/revisions),

[image]

will give you links such as https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8149545/1.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the chain button.[image]

Comment: Hah, nice. Didn't see that

Comment: Hmm, it's not exactly the same url. The former also has a `/posts/` in the path...

Comment: Oopsie, so it is. Well, at least you know the "proper" way of doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I'm looking for a link to the revision *as it is shown in the revision list*, especially since it shows the difference between that revision and the previous one. As the author asks for an *anchor*, he might have intended that too (but please let me know if I'm wrong).

That feature is available too (and has been for a couple of years, but not back in 2011). It is not really discoverable; you have to open the developer tools of your browser and inspect the HTML:

[image]

You'll see that the body of the revision (not the header, unfortunately) has an `id` attribute, so you can copy it: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8149545/revisions#rev-body-56c3139b-04f7-47c1-8a3a-fab0270ccaa7. Not too different from your original suggestion!