# Add anchors to the top of each revision element on the timeline pages

Tags: feature-request, timeline, anchor

While in response to the request [*Add anchors to revisions*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112379/341145) it is apparent that [there is a link to each revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112380/341145). I often prefer to link to a revision within the context of the entire timeline of the post - for example, so the differences compared to previous versions are visible.

I see that there are anchors underneath the blue bar that contains the revision number and details. It would be nice to have an anchor above the bar, so anyone clicking the link to the anchor would have more clues about the revision without having to scroll up.

Please add an anchor to the top of each revision bar:

[image: screenshot with arrow pointing above bar]

Chris Pederick's [Web Developer toolbar](https://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) was used to highlight the existing anchors in the screenshot above.